# React how to call componentDidMount every time when switching between ListItem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, jsx, listitem

When initializing widget component which loads various charts it works as it should, but when switching to another ListItem , componentDidMount do not load when switch to another item. I need to load it, because it fetch required data for it. But the thing is when I am switching between ListItem did not initialize componentDidMount

DashboardSidebar.jsx

```
class DashboardSidebar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tabLocation: this.props.tabLocation
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }
  onChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      tabLocation: event.target.value
    });
  }
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { path } = this.props.match;
    const { reports = [], sites = [] } = this.props;

    let fromFilterString = "-"
    let toFilterString = "-"

    return (
      <Drawer
        className={classes.drawer}
        variant="permanent"
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawerPaper,
        }}>
        <div>
          <List>
            {reports.map((report) => (
              <ListItem 
              onClick={this.onChange} button key={report.id}>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  <DashboardIcon />
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText
                  disableTypography
                  primary={
                    <Typography type="body2">
                      <Link to={`${path}/${report.slug}`} style={{ color: "#000" }}>
                        {report.name}
                      </Link>
                    </Typography>
                  }
                />
              </ListItem>
            ))}
          </List>
        </div>
        <Divider light />
      </Drawer>
    )
  }
}
```

This component seems run correct, but when clicking on other `ListItem` run `componentDidUpdate` which do not fetch required data for charts. Also I find out that when I changed in MainDashboard component `key={i}` to `key={l.id}` is started to hit `componentDidMount`, but then widget's do not load, but from Console I can see that it hit `componentDidMount` and fetch data which I `console.log()`  .

MainDashboard.jsx

```
class MainDashboard extends Component {
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.match.params.report === prevProps.match.params.report) {
      return true;
    }
    let widgets = {};
    let data = {};
    let layout = {};
    fetch(...)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        ...
        this.setState({dashboard: data, isLoading: false, layouts: layout });
      })
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ mounted: true, isLoading: true });
    let widgets = {};
    let data = {};
    let layout = {};

    fetch(...
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
          ...
        this.setState({dashboard: data, isLoading: false, layouts: layout });
      })
  }

  sortWidgets(widgets) {
    ...
    return widgets;
  }

  generateDOM() {
    return _.map(this.state.dashboard.widgets, function(l, i) {
        ....
      return (
        <div key={i}>
            <ChartWidget
              visualization={l.visualization}
              name={l.visualization.name}
        </div>
      );
    }.bind(this));
  }
  render() {

    return (
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: In HTML or [React synthetic events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html) you don't get `evt.value`, but `evt.target.value`, so the following: `_onSwitchTab = (value) => ...` is invalid, it should be `_onSwitchTab = (evt) => { const value = evt.target.value`. If it doesn't work then, you should show us what the function `setCurrentDashboard` does

Comment: @Tyblitz I changed on ```_onSwitchTab``` from ```value``` to ```evt``` and set into value , but it doesnt work. Yes I will update my question with setCurrentDashboard

Comment: @PrakashKarena no, ```_onSwitchTab``` is not the issue

Comment: you want to call your fetch request in BaseDashboard.jsx when any link <Link to={`${path}/${report.slug}`} /> in DashboardSidebar.jsx is clicked.Am i right ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So `componentDidMount` is actually being hit but nothing is happening in terms of data updates? in that case, your component loads/mounts first and whatever needs to happen doesn't trigger a re-render, I would look into using another lifecycle method to ensure that your data is updated.

I'm not sure if you're working on a legacy system but if upgrading to functional components is an option, I would recommend using the lifecycle method `useEffect` because it replaces many lifecycle methods like `componentDidMount` , `componentDidUpdate` and the unsafe `componentWillUnmount` and will make your life a whole lot easier and more efficient.

Comment: A re-render will not re-execute `componentDidMount`.

Answer (score 3):

You have three option:
1- Use another life cycle such as `componentDidUpdate`, fetch the new data if there is particular change in props or state
2- Use a new `Key`, if you use a new key on a component, it will trigger a `componentDidMount`, because the component is rendered again as a new entity
3- Use [react.ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)
I think you should read up on all three choices and choose one that will fit you the best.

Answer (score 1):

`componentDidMount` is only executed when a component is mounted.
A state update in `DashboardSidebar` would not cause `BaseDashboard` to be re-mounted so `componentDidMount` will not be re-executed for `BaseDashboard`.

Have you tried fetching the data in the `onChange` event handler (for switching to another `ListItem`) instead?